# Matplotlib Spyder3.2.6 Plotting a lot of information and creating space

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I am just starting out using Spyder and doing some simple data analysis. I have some census data that I have filtered. The data is pretty large 32k entries. As you will see I have filtered the census data into age, and hours per week. But when I went to plot it, the information is really scrunched together. I have been searching the internet trying to find a way to separate the values, but I am just coming up short. Any help would be great! Thanks

[Picture of Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq28G.png)

[Data information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2lgU.png)

```
df = pd.read_csv('adult.data.csv', header=None,  delimiter=',')    


  native_country = np.array(df[13])

  united_states = native_country[0]

  native_country_us = df.loc[(df[13] == united_states)]

  native_country_us_hours_per_week = np.array(native_country_us[12])

  native_country_us_age = np.array(native_country_us[0])


plt.plot(native_country_us_hours_per_week, native_country_us_age, "go")

plt.xlabel('Hours per week')
plt.ylabel('Age of US Citizen')
plt.title('Hours Per Week US Citizen Works')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you plugging the Y values into the plot.

try:

```
plt.plot(native_country_us_hours_per_week, native_country_us_age , "go")
```